# How to use the same callback as the arrow in GTK Treeview?

Tags: c, treeview, gtk

If you're familiar with GTK Treeviews, they have an arrow on the left side that allows the expansion of that row. I'd like to hook up this functionality to clicking the row itself, using `g_object_set(G_OBJECT(view), "activate-on-single-click", TRUE, NULL);` and `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(view), "row-activated", callback, data);`. Right now, I have a callback that causes some problems, but if I expand the tree view row with the arrow, these problems disappear.

Is there any easy way to do this? I was thinking about using [gtk_tree_view_row_activated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-row-activated), but I'm not sure how to package the data that goes into the `data` parameter of `g_signal_connect`.

Some additional resources:

[g_signal_connect()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect)

[GTK TreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html)

[g_object_set()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set)

If there's anything else I can provide, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [expand_row](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-expand-row). The callback for [row-activated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated) will provide you with the TreePath.